# Retrieving individual values within a list in Sass

Tags: sass

Say I've got something like this:

```
$padding = 5px 25px;
$border  = 1px solid #f00;
```

Can I retreive the single values? Something like

```
$padding-vertical = $padding[0];  // returns 5px;
or:
$padding-vertical = $padding(top); // returns 5px
or:
$border-size      = $border[border-width]; // return 1px
$border-color     = $border(border-color); // return #f00
etc...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nth()` function is the only way to retrieve specific items in a list, and it requires knowing its position.

```
$padding-vertical = nth($padding, 1);  // returns 5px;
```

Because many shorthand properties don't require all values to be set, you might not get the results you're looking for.  For the variables you've provided, this will work:

```
$border-size      = nth($border, 1); // return 1px
$border-color     = nth($border, 3); // return #f00
```